# Roblox Error: Expected ')' to close '(' at column 3), got '='

Tags: lua, roblox

Hi I am a user on Roblox and I am trying to script a light switch that turns off 4 lights and I am having a error (it's in the title)

There are 2 blocks being used, the Off4 and On4 switch.

My code is

```
function OnClicked()
if (workspace.LivingRoomLight.SpotLight.Enabled == true) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight2.SpotLight.Enabled == true) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight3.SpotLight.Enabled == true) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight4.SpotLight.Enabled == true) then
    (workspace.LivingRoomLight.SpotLight.Enabled = false) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight2.SpotLight.Enabled == false) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight3.SpotLight.Enabled == false) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight3.SpotLight.Enabled == false)
    script.Parent.Transparency = 1
    workspace.Off4.Transparency = 0
end
end
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(OnClicked)
```

The other scripts (that work) I use in the ones that use only one light is

```
function OnClicked()
if (workspace.Hallwaylight.SpotLight.Enabled == true) then
    workspace.Hallwaylight.SpotLight.Enabled = false
    script.Parent.Transparency = 1
    workspace.Off.Transparency = 0
end
end
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(OnClicked)
```

Note: I am only using the on scripts because that's the only one I edited for the one with the error. The error in the on script is the first = at column 3 and when I use '==' instead of '=' then the whole line becomes a error

Comment: Just put conditions in brackets ( if() ) not operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (workspace.LivingRoomLight.SpotLight.Enabled == true) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight2.SpotLight.Enabled == true) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight3.SpotLight.Enabled == true) and (workspace.LivingRoomLight4.SpotLight.Enabled == true) then
    workspace.LivingRoomLight.SpotLight.Enabled = false
    workspace.LivingRoomLight2.SpotLight.Enabled = false
    workspace.LivingRoomLight3.SpotLight.Enabled = false
    workspace.LivingRoomLight4.SpotLight.Enabled = false
    ...
```

Some pointers:

- `x == y` means “does `x` equal `y`?”. It’s a **condition** (either true or false).
- `x = y` means “set `x` to `y`”. It’s a **statement** (a command to your program to modify the value of `x`).
- `and` is an operator that expects **conditions** to its left and right.

Your program is of the form

```
if (these four values are true) then
  set each of them to false
end
```

so you need `and` and `==` on the first line, but they don’t make sense inside the `if` — you need four simple statements using `=`, there.

---

You don’t really *need* `==` though. Comparing boolean values (like `workspace.LivingRoomLight.SpotLight.Enabled`, which are already `true` or `false`) to `true` is a bit silly: instead of `if x == true then ... end` it’s nicer to just write `if x then ... end`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I’m glad :) Could you accept my answer (click the ✓) so your question shows up as resolved?

Comment: If they don’t understand `if`, it’s in no way my job to teach them about `for`. It hurt to write that snippet of code, but beginners deserve a focused Q&A experience too — and the OP’s question was not about `for`.